# html form content and css alignment issues

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-float

I have a user registration form with a submit button and a cancel button,

**Problem 1)** I can't have those two buttons inside the single form, if I have the cancel button inside the form with `submit button`, when I click the `cancel button`, it execute the action of the form instead of going to home and cancelling the registration page.

Can't we have these two buttons inside a single form..?

**Problem 2)** Because of Problem 1, I added the `cancel button` outside the form and linking to the home page, it works as I expect, but, I need to have those two `button` in the same row on the screen.

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="login-container">
        <form id="user-registration-form" method="POST">
            // Some other fields, like username, etc.
            <fieldset class="edit" id="submit-button-fieldset">

                <input type="submit" id="submit-regiser"/>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
        <fieldset id="Cancel-field">
          <button id='cancel-registration' onclick=window.location.href='link-to-home'>Cancel</button>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I need to have those `#submit-regiser` and `#cancel-registration` in the same row in the screen. And this is for mobile browser, so should obey `XHTML` rules

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Add the whole page and your css. Maybe use jsfiddle.

Comment: @Baszz : It's is very huge file, and, I don't have any syntax issues. I just want a solution for these problems.

Comment: Than just add the pieces that matter...

Answer (score 1):

That's the intended behavior. Cancel buttons are supposed to clear the form, not to take one back to what page ever.

Still you can do it this way using the `<button>` element:

```
<form id="user-registration-form" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="edit" id="submit-button-fieldset">
        <button type="submit" id="submit-regiser">submit</button>
        <button id="cancel-regiser" onClick="window.location.href='http://example.com'; return false;">Back</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it Ok, to have a button instead of `input submit` field?

Comment: No use, Cancel button execute the form's action method instead of going back!

Comment: My fault. @KugathasanAbimaran is right. I modified the above code.